# How should I use Gatsby.js to generate both the thumbnails and full-size images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

What should I do if I need both a thumbnail(i.e. low resolution version) of a picture and the full size version.

I have a medium style image zoom component(https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-butterfly-w78l5) and I want that component to show the thumbnails and only when it is being clicked on and it gets zoomed out it shows the full-size picture by specifying different url to `src` and `enlargedSrc`.

this is how I query all my images files

```
const ImageSupplier = () => {
  const { allFile } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allFile(
        filter: {
          extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/" }
          sourceInstanceName: { eq: "imageFolder" }
        }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(
                maxWidth: 800
                quality: 95 
              ) {
                originalName
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);
```

But it only gives me the full-size image with `fluid.src`, it also comes with a `srcSet` but I have no idea how to use `srcSet` to achieve what I want.

Comment: this article gives a good idea of querying for and working with different image sizes: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-11-03-building-an-accessible-lightbox/

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use [Gatsby-Image](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/).
2. You query for the images twice. You use [fixed](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#fixed-queries) with a low resolution for thumbnails. You keep using your current implementation the full-size images.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply! but how do I make the image zoom component to show thumbnails when it is not clicked on and to show full size when it is zooming?